# Play sound from blob data returned from server via AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, azure-cognitive-services

I'm issuing an AJAX request to get audio data from the server.
The server sends a REST call which sends back (to the client) the result (blob data)
I want to play the sound to the client.
Here's is the result I got back from the server:

[image]

EDITED:
This is the JS part:

```
 var audio = new window.Audio();
        audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
        var promise = audio.play();
```

This is the html part:

```
<audio id="myAudioElement" muted="muted" crossOrigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: `new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(req.response)).play();` assuming you really requested a Blob.

Comment: tried it - I get an exception: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided. Added a screenshot of the response I got

Comment: This means that what you passed to createObjectURL method was not a Blob. To get it, you need to tell the browser you want it as a Blob. If you did the request from XMLHttpRequest API, then you need to set your req object's `.responseType="blob";`

Comment: ok. So I have tried doing it. I moved one step further but now I get "Failed to load because no supported source was found." Do I need to define something else?
Edited original post

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: Not yet. The current state is that I get "Failed to load because no supported source was found." I updated my original post with more info.